# YAML Multiple response for single status code

Tags: json, yaml

Help me with multiple response body with single status code in yaml format.

Ex::

```
'401':
  description: Not Found
  headers:
    Content-Type :
      type: string
      default: application/json;charset=UTF-8
  examples:
    errorCode: '48'
    errorLabel: RONotAllowed
    errorDescription: Unable to execute the remote operation as it is not allowed for the vehicle
'401':
  description: Not Found
  headers:
    Content-Type :
      type: string
      default: application/json;charset=UTF-8
  examples:
    errorCode: '45'
    errorLabel: VehicleNotFound
    errorDescription: Vehicle could not be found using VIN provided  in request
'401':
  description: Not Found
  headers:
    Content-Type :
      type: string
      default: application/json;charset=UTF-8
  examples:
    errorCode: '49'
    errorLabel: VehicleAlreadyOnline
    errorDescription: Unable to execute the remote operation since   vehicle is already online
```

Using above code i found error 
✖ YAML Syntax Error
Duplicated mapping key at line 608, column 9: '401'

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly you are trying to provide a list of examples for the error code. For this you need:

```
'401':
  description: Not Found
  headers:
    Content-Type :
      type: string
      default: application/json;charset=UTF-8
  examples:
    - errorCode: '48'
      errorLabel: RONotAllowed
      errorDescription: 'Unable to execute the remote operation as it is not allowed for the vehicle'
    - errorCode: '45'
      errorLabel: VehicleNotFound
      errorDescription: 'Vehicle could not be found using VIN provided  in request'
    - errorCode: '49'
      errorLabel: VehicleAlreadyOnline
      errorDescription: 'Unable to execute the remote operation since   vehicle is already online'
```

Comment: I tried with given syntax and found an error on swagger editor  **✖ Swagger Error

Additional properties not allowed: 401**

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the swagger editor at all but the above snippet is valid yaml, you can check it here http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/